# how to add title to column with graphics

Tags: beamer

I have divided my frame into two columns. Each column has a picture and itemized text. I am trying to add a title at the top of each column but that is not working.
I would like to have a title on the top-center of each column

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns} 
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
    First Column
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red] (0.46,0.56) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.75cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \end{itemize} 

   \column{0.5\textwidth}
    Second Column
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[green] (0.46,0.56) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.75cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \end{itemize} 

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing on the same line as First/Second Column titles (Remember: `LaTeX` does not add a new line when you simply press `Return` on the keyboard). Adding a `\centering` at the begining of each column can easily fix this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns} 
  \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    First Column\\[.2cm]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red] (0.46,0.56) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.75cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \end{itemize} 
  \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    Second Column\\[.2cm]    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[green] (0.46,0.56) ellipse (0.9cm and 0.75cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \end{itemize} 
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]