# Resizing graphic to show relative size

Tags: beamer, graphics, columns

I have divided my frame in two columns. Both columns have titles,picture,itemized text as in [how to add title to column with graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246865/how-to-add-title-to-column-with-graphics)
the only difference is that I am adding graphics in my frame as opposed to drawing cycles in the above mentioned question. I want to resize one of the pictures without changing the location of title and text. I tried doing this by 
`\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.4\textheight]{my_pic}` but the problem is that it changes the location of everything that is there in this column. 
How can I change the size of my picture without disturbing the position of other stuff in that column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place the image in a `\parbox` and specify the height of that box. Say both your images originally had `height=3cm`. Add the `\parbox` with a height of 3cm, then you can reduce the size of the image inside, without the list below moving up.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns} 
  \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    First Column\\[.2cm]
   \parbox[t][3cm][t]{\linewidth}{\centering\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-16x10}}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \end{itemize} 
  \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    Second Column\\[.2cm]    
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-16x10}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \end{itemize} 
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to distribute the white space(below smaller figure) in first column such that figure appears in middle rather than being at top.

Comment: @NAASI Change the second `[t]` for the `\parbox` to `[c]`, i.e. `\parbox[t][3cm][c]{...`. That optional argument specifies the vertical alignment of the content within the box.